# Colors on Roller Coaster Tycoon 1 Deluxe are messed up

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

So I recently bought Roller Coaster Tycoon Deluxe during the steam sale, so I can reminisce and feel the nostalgia of the game. So when I first ran the game, the game started up normally, but all the colors were messed up. Ex. When it first starts the game, the background where it shows the hasbro logo scrolling down is pink, and the textures of the game looks like its opposite of what it should be. Does anyone else have or had this problem, because I really want to play this game.

Comment: Try compatibility mode? I couldn't get it to work with a steam copy (which sucked) but I re-bought it on GoG and that copy worked in compatiblity mode.

Comment: I changed it to compatibility mode, but it still had the same problem as before. I also tried it with different service packs, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: you could try running it on a VM

Comment: I've seen that problem as well, but since I currently don't have RCT at hand and haven't played it in at least a year, I can't give you a definite answer. Have you tried alt-tabbing out and back in again?

Comment: What operating system are you setting compatibility mode to use? Roller Coaster Tycoon was originally designed for Windows 95. If that doesn't work, it may be an issue with the way Steam is starting the game.

Comment: a image of the problem would help

Answer (score 1):

Go into the game, start new game, go into options, and then change the window to (well) windowed!

Comment: Changing to windowed mode fixed the problem for me when running on Linux via `wine`.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your desktop, and open the screen where you can change your resolution. Leave it open, then start the game.

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score -2):

I got a similar problem some years ago with Age of Empires 2. The solution was to tab out of the game and kill explorer.exe. It is possible to create a batch file, so you dont have to do it everytime on your own.

taskkill /F /IM Explorer.exe 
age2_x1.exe 
Start explorer.exe

Instead of "age2_x1.exe" you have to use the path to your Roller Coaster Tycoon Deluxe exe.
The batch will kill Explorer.exe and start the game afterwards. When you close your game, explorer.exe will be restarted.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/age-of-empires-2-on-windows-7-has-color-issues/a1763d12-11e2-498f-9b23-122792b14f74)